# Tensorflow: generate label map file

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trainig an object detection model via TF.
I have a dynamically generated list of classes. So I'm not able to prepare label_map.pbtxt manually.

I'm looking for better way to generate it.

Which format is it? It is a JSON, protobuf, etc?
I want to take an appropriate library in Python to generate this format file.

Comment: Do you plan to use the pbtxt file in openCV ?

Comment: I guess no. I'm going to use it to train an object detection model via TF.